# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in python mysql login

Tags: python, mysql

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/Stig/Desktop/python/main.py   
File "C:/Users/Stig/Desktop/python/main.py", line 9
    if(query.execute("SELECT * FROM 'USERS' where 'username'" + `username` + "' AND `password`='" + `password`)):
                                                                ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[Code:](http://pastebin.com/yGrbTAZm)

```
import MySQLdb
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def makeLoggedInWindow():
    if(query.execute("SELECT * FROM 'USERS' where 'username'", 'username',  "' AND `password`='", 'password', "'")):
        window = Tk()
        db.commit()
        label_3 = Label(window, text="Du er nu logget ind!")
        label_3.pack()
    else:
        db.commit()
        print ("Login fejlede!")

label = Label(root, text="Velkommen til mit log ind script!")
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="root",
                     db="users")

query = db.cursor()

loop = 'true'
label_1 = Label(root, text="Username: ")
label_2 = Label(root, text="Password: ")
username = Entry(root)
password = Entry(root, show='*')
button_1 = Button(root, text="Log ind!", command=makeLoggedInWindow)

label_1.pack()
label_2.pack()
username.pack()
password.pack()
button_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

can somebody help?

Comment: Please post the code inline, not as a link

Comment: But my code is to long

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: def makeLoggedInWindow():
    if(query.execute("SELECT * FROM 'schema' where 'username'='%s' AND 'password'='%s'" %(username,password))):
        window = Tk()
        db.commit()
        label_3 = Label(window, text="Du er nu logget ind!")
        label_3.pack()

Comment: You are doing the mother of all application mistakes in your code. Do not build your query with the normal string concatenations. This will make it vulnerable to SQL injections. In your case it will allow everyone to log in as every user my manipulating the username and password strings.

Comment: But what is the syntax error?

Comment: Missing `=` after `'username'`. It is likely a MySQL syntax error, as I can't see any python syntax errors there. Oh, except that you're not concatenating string, but passing 5 parameters to `execute`, but it should not give Syntax error.

Comment: The code in the traceback does not agree with the pasted code.  You have `('string' + \`string\` + ...)` where the code shows `('string', 'string', ...)`

Comment: Now i got Can't convert 'Entry' object to str implicitly

Comment: This *is* a Python `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 1):

Your traceback reveals that you are using the older `repr` syntax - the `` `backticks` ``. And that the code that you presented here is not correct.

The backticks did work in Python 2 but no longer in Python 3.

All in all, this technique is **deeply flawed** - `repr` is not guaranteed to give SQL compatible output; and you will be vulnerable to SQL injection. You should be using the placeholders in SQL queries instead:

```
query.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS where username = %s AND password = %s", 
    (username, password))
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing `=` after `username` field name. Also why don't you use python command substitution for better clarity:

```
"SELECT * FROM USERS where username={0} AND password={1}".format(username,password)
```